# Can thinktecture identity server be configured to allow Federated Identity with Multiple Partners

Tags: claims-based-identity, federated-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

I have the following challenge:

1. My company needs to enable SSO for a customer that has its own ADFS instance & IP in place.  (in the future I'm sure we will need to federate with other companies too)
2. We also need to continue to support customers authenticating against our SQL database.

Basically I think what I need to do is set this up as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446524.aspx, but I would like to do this all using thinktecture identity server and not use ADFS.

To support #2 We're using thinktecture identity server because it can easily be configured as an STS & IDP that queries an existing SQL DB.

Can thinktecture be setup to support both 1 & 2?  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yep - that's both supported in v2.

See also: https://vimeo.com/51666379

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: not sure if that video answers #2. @leastprevilege - can you provide clarification?